# Can someone explain to me what filter width is

Tags: deep-learning

I am a beginner in deep learning. Can someone explain to me what filter width is in the context of CNN? How is that different from kernel size? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you that kernel, filter and feature detector are the same. 
The kernel will have a size which is height * width. filter width means kernel 
width.

Kindly refer this [Understanding of CNN](https://medium.com/@RaghavPrabhu/understanding-of-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-deep-learning-99760835f148) as well for better understanding.

Hope this will help you.